# Why doesn't MDN's `Object.create` polyfill set `prototype.constructor`?

Tags: javascript, es5-shim

**Considering [MDN's `Object.create` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill):**

```
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
  (function () {
    var F = function () {};
    Object.create = function (o) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) { throw Error('Second argument not supported');}
      if (o === null) { throw Error('Cannot set a null [[Prototype]]');}
      if (typeof o != 'object') { throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');}
      F.prototype = o;
      return new F();
    };
  })();
}
```

**Focusing particularly on these two lines:**

```
F.prototype = o;
return new F();
```

**I was wondering, why isn't it appropriate to set `F.prototype.constructor = F;`?**

```
F.prototype = o;
F.prototype.constructor = F;  // why not?
return new F();
```

Comment: Why do you want to set `constructor` to `F`? It is just an internal helper. What would be the advantage?

Comment: An additional thing is that polyfills should mimic the behavior as close as possible and (without being able to test right now) the given polyfill should evaluate `({}).constructor == Object.create({}).constructor` to `true` as it does for the native `Object.create`

Comment: I think t.niese's second comment (about accurate mimicry, rather than ideal behavior) is the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering, why isn't it appropriate to set F.prototype.constructor = F;?

`F` is a temporary function, and it seems intentional that there is no way to reference it from outside `Object.create`.